# Im install tabulate but not working python 3.9? How to solve this problem

Tags: python

```
import pip
from tabulate import tabulate
l=[(1,'ayushi',100),(2,'ayush',200),(3,'aadhivik',199)]
print(tabulate(l,header=l,tablefmt='preety'))




Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rasum\Desktop\tab.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tabulate import tabulate
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabulate'
```

Comment: Why are you importing `pip` into your script? Also, are you sure that the module has been installed correctly, and into the correct version of Python? If you issue the command `python -m pip list` does the Module you want to use show up?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how installation of packages works, my dear friend.
You need to install the respective package from PyPI using `pip`:

```
pip install tabulate
```